# Hibernate Query to find distance between two points

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, hql

I am able to find the distance using -

```
String hqlQuery = "SELECT *, (6371 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((:ulatitude - abs(phy_1)) * pi()/180 / 2),2) +" +
                     "COS(:ulatitude * pi()/180 ) * COS(abs(phy_1) * pi()/180) *" +
                     "POWER(SIN((:ulongitude - phy_2) * pi()/180 / 2), 2)))) as d " +
                     "FROM location l HAVING distance < 10 ORDER BY d";
            Query query = getSession().createSQLQuery(hqlQuery);


            query.setParameter("ulatitude", latitude);
            query.setParameter("ulongitude", longitude);
            return query.list();
```

The problem is that my model doesn't contain distance as a field. And I am unable to figure out as -
1. How to change this to a proper HQL instead of using SQL query.
2. How to return this additional parameter distance `d` as distance is not a field in my model for `location`.

I tried with -

```
String hql = "from location where (SELECT (6371 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((:ulatitude - abs(phy_1)) * pi()/180 / 2),2) +" +
                     "COS(:ulatitude * pi()/180 ) * COS(abs(phy_1) * pi()/180) *" +
                     "POWER(SIN((:ulongitude - phy_2) * pi()/180 / 2), 2))))) < 10";

Query query = getSession().createQuery(hql);
```

But it gives following error -

`org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected end of subtree`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do away with following -

```
String hql= "from location c where (6371 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((:ulatitude - abs(c.phy_!)) * pi()/180 / 2),2) +" +
                     "COS(:ulatitude * pi()/180 ) * COS(abs(c.phy_1) * pi()/180) *" +
                     "POWER(SIN((:ulongitude - c.phy_2) * pi()/180 / 2), 2)))) < 10";
```